# No internet connection debian

Tags: debian, dhcp, internet, firmware

My internet connection doesn't work on Debian after a fresh install.
This is what I encountered after a couple of hours searching:

My ifconfig has an eth0 entry.
cat interfaces returns

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interfcae
auto lo
iface io inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

(I added auto eth0 and iface eth0 inet dhcp manually)

My routing table ('route' and 'route -n') are empty (also after `/etc/init.d/networking restart`)

`ping 8.8.8.8` returns Network is unreachable

and `route add default gw 192.168.1.1` returns :

```
SIOCADDRT: Network is unreachable
```

I googled a lot and I couldn't find and answer.
This is after a fresh install, during the install the networking part failed as well and I figured to not configure it yet and do it manually after the install.
After the install I installed the firmware:  `firmware-realtek_0.43_all.deb` file (downloaded from [here](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/firmware/) ) with `dpkg -i firmware-realtek_0.43_all.deb`

Comment: Bring eth0 up: `ifup eth0`

Comment: I guess it's possible that the lack of non-free firmware in Debian is significant here, but have you confirmed that? For example, does your ethernet connection already work fine with a different distro which packages those drivers by default?

Comment: What is the output of `ip link` and `ip addr`?

Comment: @IporSircer The output is 'interface eth0 already configured'

Comment: @SauceCode I haven't tried yet. I could install Ubuntu as well and then remove it after I have tested it, though.

Comment: @aventurin for 'ip link' I get "eth0: <BROADCAST, MULTICAST, UP, LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether (HWADDR) brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff.  For 'ip addr' I get the same output and then my inet6 addrs

Comment: @RensOliemans You could run a live CD to save the bother of installing it. Either way, it's a good idea to isolate the problem and make sure there's no issue with the connection itself, before you start changing your debian settings.

Comment: @SauceCode Thanks for the tip. I ran Ubuntu without installing it and I indeed had the same problem. Pinging any IP address resulted in `Network is unreachable`. In 'Network' under 'System Settings', Ubuntu could recognize that my connection was 1000Mb/s and I could see the IP address, however it was unusable.

Comment: @RensOliemans So doesn't sound like a Debian settings issue at all. Can you ping inside your network, e.g. your router?

Comment: @SauceCode Okay after some testing I figured something out. The problem occured on my desktop, on Debian and Ubuntu. I now installed Windows 10 and it works perfectly. However, on my (dual boot) laptop, the ethernet connection also stopped working on Ubuntu, yet not on Windows (a week ago it worked perfectly). I know that this is a different issue, however do you have any clue what the problem could be?

Comment: @RensOliemans So on both desktop and laptop, ethernet works on Windows and ethernet doesn't work on Debian/Ubuntu? To be honest I've no idea why that would be, but I think we're outside the scope of the comments by now.

Comment: @SauceCode Sorry for the late reply, but yes. This was indeed ouside of the scope of the comments, however I 'fixed' the problem. I re-registered my machines at my campus' administration system and waited a day, and it worked again. So, it's fixed, but thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your `/etc/resolv.conf` file with:

```
domain <provider-address.com>
search <provider-address.com>
nameserver <first-provider-ip>
nameserver <second-provider-ip>
```

Comment: At least for testing, you can use one of Google's public DNS servers, so you could add `nameserver 4.2.2.2`

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is fixed now.
I didn't do too much myself, however the problem was that with my ethernet connection, I didn't have any internet connection on any Unix OS (granted, I only tested Debian and Ubuntu (although on two separate machines)), however it did work on Windows 10.

I didn't understand this and simply re-registered my devices at my campus' administration system, waited a day, and now it works. Thanks for the replies!